# ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range on event subscription

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
1:      public enum ScriptType
2:      {
3:          FirstScript,
4:          SecondScript
5:      }
6: 
7:      public class BossHandler
8:      {
9:          public delegate void BossBarUpdate(int hitPower);
10:         public ScriptType scriptType;
11:         public FirstScript firstScript;
12:         public SecondScript secondScript;
13: 
14:         private void Start()
15:         {
16:             bossHealthBar = FindObjectOfType<BossHealthBar>();
17:             switch (scriptType)
18:             {
19:                 case ScriptType.First:
20:                     if (firstScript != null)
21:                     firstScript.bossBarUpdate += bossHealthBar.UpdateFillers;
22:                     break;
23:                 case ScriptType.Second:
24:                     if (secondScript != null)
25:                     secondScript.bossBarUpdate += bossHealthBar.UpdateFillers;            
26:                     break;
27:             }
28:         }
29:     }
30:
31:     public class FirstScript
32:     {
33:         public event BossHandler.BossBarUpdate bossBarUpdate;
34: 
35:         public void HurtInAWay(int hitpower) 
36:         {
37:             bossBarUpdate.Invoke();
38:         }
39:     }
40:
41:     public class SecondScript
42:     {
43:         public event BossHandler.BossBarUpdate bossBarUpdate;
44: 
45:         public void HurtInAnotherWay(int hitpower) 
46:         {
47:             bossBarUpdate.Invoke();
48:         }
49:     }
50:
51:     public class BossHealthBar
52:     {
53:         public void UpdateFillers(int hitPower) 
54:         {
55:             // Updates health bar fillers. 
56:         }
57:     }
```

BossHandler is a script that works as an interface between 3 scripts, BossHealthBar, FirstScript that handles a type of enemies, and SecondScript that handles another type.

It's giving me the following exception:
`ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.` with the rest of the details being the files this exception came from.
The exception is given in the Start function on construction, on the lines 21 and 25.

Knowing that first and second scripts can be off (disabled) when BossHandler gets constructed, is it a cause? If not, then what could be causing it, and what's the solution?

Note: execution order on all scripts is not changed.

Comment: What is the whole exception?

Comment: And please indicate on which line this occurs

Comment: I'll add these details immediately to the post.

Comment: The details were added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to initialize events in your FirstScript and SecondScript:

```
public event BossHandler.BossBarUpdate bossBarUpdate = delegate {  };
```

Second problem: Before subscribing, check if BossHealthBar has been found:

```
 var bossHealthBar = FindObjectOfType<BossHealthBar>();
 switch (scriptType)
 {
    case ScriptType.FirstScript:
       if (firstScript != null && bossHealthBar != null)
       ...
    case ScriptType.SecondScript:
       if (secondScript != null && bossHealthBar != null)
       ...
  }
```

You may also replace your delegate from FirstScript and SecondScript

```
public event BossHandler.BossBarUpdate bossBarUpdate;
```

to

```
public event Action<int> bossBarUpdate;
```

In that way you dont need any initialization for Action, like it was with delegate:

```
public event Action<int> bossBarUpdate;
 
public void HurtInAWay(int hitpower) 
{
    bossBarUpdate?.Invoke(hitpower);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the BossHealthBar that caused all the issues.